# best way to give permission to admin website user to modify public site?

Tags: php, linux, debian

I have a website, let's call it "public" with an admin site, let's call it "admin."

Both websites are hosted on the same Debian server and each site is owned by a different user: `public_user` and `admin_user`

public site is in `var/www/public`

admin is in `var/www/admin`

Now; using php `mkdir()` and `copy()` from the admin site I would like:

1) Create a folder inside the public site.

2) `move`/`copy` files within public from the admin site.

From admin I would like to do the following inside public:

Create a folder in `www/public/assets/images`

Move images from `www/public/assets/temp` to my newly created folder

At the moment I have "permission denied"; I could `chmod 777` but surely there must be a safer and better way?

What would the pros do?

Comment: You should chown the files to the correct user/group and chmod the permissions you want (777 = xyz, x=user, y=group, z=everybody). I think you might want to write more about what you're doing - having the site copy files/folders sounds like the wrong approach.

Comment: do you mean that if I assign both users to the same group and chown the files with this group then I can chmod the files 775 and that would work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability to setup user groups on the server,

1. Setup a new user group
2. Assign both public_user and admin_user to the group
3. Then assign the desired folder(s) [www/public/assets/images] to the group with read/write (and if necessary, execute) permissions.
4. After that, you should be able to copy files/move files to said folder as either user.

For more info, refer to the [Debian administration documentation for adding groups and adding users to those groups](http://www.debianadmin.com/users-and-groups-administration-in-linux.html).